# How to still get an output if the website doesn't exist. (how to handle Error 404)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, http-status-code-404

Here is the code:

```
quote_page =  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + Awi
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
wiki_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'mw-parser-output'})
wikip = wiki_box.find('p')
wiki = wikip.text.strip()
print wiki
```

Awi is the keyword for the wiki site. But what if the site doesn't exists. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You could simply check `page.getcode()` according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), couldn't you?

Comment: Have you tried try: except: blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use try&except

```
import urllib2
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
except urllib2.URLError as e:
    print(e.args)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the request status code and see if it meets HTTP CODE 200

```
quote_page =  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + Awi
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
if page.getcode() == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    wiki_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'mw-parser-output'})
    wikip = wiki_box.find('p')
    wiki = wikip.text.strip()
    print(wiki)
else:
    print("Page could not be loaded")
```